# Read() call returns -1 in prime sieve program

Tags: c, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

I am trying to implement a concurrent prime sieve program. Each pipe will eliminate the multiples of the current number. For example, the first pipe will eliminate all the multiples of 2 and send the non-multiples to the next pipe, the next pipe will eliminate all multiples of 3 and so on. Here is a more detailed description, but it is pretty simple: [Detailed](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/thread/).  My code is the following:

```
void receiveAndSend(int wr[35][2], int pipeNr) {
    int p;
    if (close(wr[pipeNr][1]) < 0) {
        perror("close 1");
    }
    if (read(wr[pipeNr][0], &p, 4) < 0) {
        perror("Read1");
    }
    
    printf("prime %d, from file descriptor %d\n", p, wr[pipeNr][0]);
    int j;
    pipeNr++;
    pipe(wr[pipeNr]);
    int cont = 0; 
    
    // enclose all of this in new fork
    int sec = fork();
    if (sec == 0) {
        //close(wr[pipeNr][0]);
        while (read(wr[pipeNr - 1][0], &j, 4) > 0) {
            if (j % p != 0) {
                // printf("%d is not divisible by %d\n", j, p);
                cont = 1;
                if (write(wr[pipeNr][1], &j, 4) < 0) {
                    perror("Write x");
                }
                // perror("test");
            }   
        }       
                    
        if (close(wr[pipeNr - 1][0]) < 0) {
            perror("close x");
        }
        // perror("test2");
        
        if (cont) {
            // printf("arrived\n");
            receiveAndSend(wr, pipeNr);
        }
        exit(0);
    }   
    if (wait(0) < 0) {
        perror("Wait Outter");
    }       
}
```

I am having a problem with the read call on line 6. When calling the function the first time, it works and read returns 4, but after the first recursive call, I am getting -1.

The first file descriptor, (`wr[0]`) is filled up with numbers 2...35. I have 35 file descriptors available, but I won't need all of them since there aren't 35 prime numbers.

The writing to the next pipe/fd happens in line 23 and works (returns 4 in each iteration).

I'm assuming there is some kind of problem with the child processes or with the closing calls, but I am not sure. I've tried all sorts of combinations already.

**Update:**

After debugging the problem on my own linux machine (and printing `errno`) as @pts suggested, I was able to make some progress. I am getting past the second iteration now with the following output:

```
prime 2, from file descriptor 3                                                                                                                                                                           
prime 3, from file descriptor 4
```

However, right after, it hangs with `errno` being "Success." The writing and `while` loop works, but right after the `while` loops, it hangs for some reason even though `errno` doesn't complain.

Comment: Recursion with forks, with pipes that are being opened and closed... This code is way too complex for the task.. and needs more explanation on the intended functionality.

Comment: My code is for sure too hacky. Sounds like recursion is not the real deal here. Do you have a hint on how I could implement it simpler?

Comment: `close(wr[pipeNr][1]); pipeNr++; close(wr[pipeNr - 1][1]);` are you closing the same thing twice?

Comment: @Remmelzwaal, yes Im not sure why I did that. I deleted one of them now.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to mix `printf()` and `read()` calls — you need to capture and react when the value returned by `read()` is `-1`, indicating an error.  Have you inspected `errno`?

Comment: I have not inspected errno because I am writing this for the xv6 OS which doesnt have it implemented :'D. Im doing the opencourseware MIT OS course for context. I did just deleted all the printf's except the printf to output the prime number p, but the problem still remains. I think I need to make the whole thing simpler as @Eugeene mentioned.

Comment: Using a 2D array for the pipes only adds complexity. It would be simpler for each filter to create a new pipe for its child. Specifically it makes the closing of the unused parts of the pipe easier. That being said I could build a working version of the algo described in your link, but it still look like a process bomb for large values: processes are added for each found prime and only terminate after last prime.

Comment: @SergeBallesta According to https://pdos.lcs.mit.edu/6.828/2022/labs/util.html which is where this exercise is from it says "you should create processes only as they are needed" but since pipes are there to communicate between processes, shouldnt there be one process per pipe? Allthough I will try to implement it so that I just create the pipes dynamically as you mentioned instead of having a big array.

Comment: Check the result of every function call, inclufing `wait(...)`. Print an error and `abort()` the process on error. By using `wait(...)`, also abort the parent process. Print the `strerror(errno)`. Run it on Linux to get the errno. Post your entire program. Post the dcpected output. Post the actual output. Run it with the smallest possible input which makes it fail.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? What havd you learned from that session?

Comment: UPDATE: @pts Dont know why I didnt have the idea of just running it on my linux machine. I did and made some progress as written in the update. It doesnt work all the way yet but I'm getting past the first iteration. After, it hangs.  More details in the post.

Comment: What i learned is that closing the reading end of the pipe prior the recursive call, made it impossible to read afterwards.

Comment: The new issue seems to be an issue with the read() call in the while loop after the second iteration. It reads all the way up to 35 but when it's supposed to return 0 (EOF), it hangs instead of returning 0.  I am not sure how to debug this because read doesn't return any errno, it  literally just hangs. Could this be a problem because I am still doing it recursively? BTW: I bountied the question because I realized it may be a bit more work to solve this than other questions.

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, please help them: 1. Post the full C source code of your program which you run on Linux. 2. Post the expected output and the actual (full) output. 3. Run the program with smaller input (e.g. only primes up to 7), see if it works, post the expected output and the actual (full) output.

Comment: read(...) finally immediately returns with 0 when all writers of the pipe have been closed (e.g. by close(...) or the process exiting). read(...) hangs when there are some writers of the pipe open, but they are not writing anything yet. What you are experiencing (read(...) hangs) may be caused by writers waiting for someting else (e.g. for their read(...) to return) before they start writing. So the bug can be anywhere (in any child process and at any code location). You may want to add additional debugging printfs: `fprintf(stderr, "debug: PID %d: writing: %s\n", (int)getpid(), "...");`

Comment: could you format the code, rename one-letter variables and remove debug logs like `perror test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by other answers, there are many problems with your code, including:

- The program is incomplete — there isn't a `main()` function, so we have to guess or decide how to write that.
- It isn't clear how your function is invoked — it seems necessary for the `main()` function to process the prime number 2 and then write the remaining numbers to a pipe.
- You have a monstrous array of 35 pairs of file descriptors for, presumably, 35 pipes, but it isn't clear why 35 was chosen.
- The array of pairs of file descriptors isn't necessary, and managing that array makes your code unnecessarily hard.

Here is a rewritten program — source code `prime31.c` and executable `prime31`.  It makes use of a number of headers and functions available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c`, `stderr.h`, `stderrloc.c`, `stderrloc.h`, `debug.c`, `debug.h` and so on in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

It takes command line arguments to control its behaviour.  It has a help message, like so:

```
Usage: prime31 [-dhoqV][-D debug][-n number]
  -d         Set debug level 3
  -h         Print this help message and exit
  -n number  Set maximum number to test (default: 50)
  -o         Do not optimize (minimize) the number of processes
  -q         Quiet mode
  -D debug   Set given debug level
  -V         Print version information and exit
```

It is verbose by default, writing copious amounts of tracking information to standard error and the prime numbers it finds to standard output.  The options can control this, of course.  By default, it finds primes up to 50.  There's an optimization in the code — when the prime number read off the pipe is bigger than the square root of the maximum number, it doesn't need to fork any more children — all the numbers on the pipe to that process are known to be prime.  The `-o` option suppresses that optimization, causing many more processes to be run.  The `-D level` option allows you to specify more verbose output still — the relevant levels are 3, 5, 7 in the code shown.

Note that the file descriptors used are 3, 4, 5 only.

The library code makes tracking PIDs and times trivial.  The code is careful to check the return value from system calls and reports errors.  The code doesn't usually produce errors any more, but that was helpful while debugging the code.  None of the library code was written for this program, though some revisions were made to `stderrloc.c` as a result of using it in this code.

Example outputs:

```
$ prime31 -q
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
$ prime31 > prime31.out
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.222 - pid=21990: Parent starts
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.223 - pid=21990: prime 2 ab initio
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.223 - pid=21990: prime 3 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.224 - pid=21991: prime 5 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.225 - pid=21992: prime 7 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.226 - pid=21993: prime 11 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.226 - pid=21993: prime 13 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.226 - pid=21993: prime 17 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.226 - pid=21993: prime 19 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.227 - pid=21993: prime 23 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.227 - pid=21993: prime 29 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.227 - pid=21993: prime 31 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.228 - pid=21993: prime 37 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.228 - pid=21993: prime 41 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.228 - pid=21993: prime 43 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.229 - pid=21993: prime 47 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.229 - pid=21992: Child 21993 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.230 - pid=21991: Child 21992 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.230 - pid=21990: Child 21991 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:18:40.230 - pid=21990: Parent exits
$ prime31 -o >prime31.out
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.056 - pid=22001: Parent starts
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.056 - pid=22001: prime 2 ab initio
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.057 - pid=22001: prime 3 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.057 - pid=22002: prime 5 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.058 - pid=22003: prime 7 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.059 - pid=22004: prime 11 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.060 - pid=22005: prime 13 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.061 - pid=22006: prime 17 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.061 - pid=22007: prime 19 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.062 - pid=22008: prime 23 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.063 - pid=22009: prime 29 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.064 - pid=22010: prime 31 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.065 - pid=22011: prime 37 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.066 - pid=22012: prime 41 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.067 - pid=22013: prime 43 from file descriptor 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.068 - pid=22014: prime 47 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.069 - pid=22014: Child 22015 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.069 - pid=22013: Child 22014 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.070 - pid=22012: Child 22013 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.070 - pid=22011: Child 22012 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.071 - pid=22010: Child 22011 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.071 - pid=22009: Child 22010 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.072 - pid=22008: Child 22009 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.072 - pid=22007: Child 22008 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.073 - pid=22006: Child 22007 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.074 - pid=22005: Child 22006 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.074 - pid=22004: Child 22005 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.075 - pid=22003: Child 22004 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.075 - pid=22002: Child 22003 exited with status 0x0400
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.076 - pid=22001: Child 22002 exited with status 0x0300
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:19:06.076 - pid=22001: Parent exits
$ prime31 -D7 > prime31.out
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.026 - pid=22078: Parent starts
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.027 - pid=22078: prime 2 ab initio
send value 3 to fd 4
send value 5 to fd 4
send value 7 to fd 4
send value 9 to fd 4
send value 11 to fd 4
send value 13 to fd 4
send value 15 to fd 4
send value 17 to fd 4
send value 19 to fd 4
send value 21 to fd 4
send value 23 to fd 4
send value 25 to fd 4
send value 27 to fd 4
send value 29 to fd 4
send value 31 to fd 4
send value 33 to fd 4
send value 35 to fd 4
send value 37 to fd 4
send value 39 to fd 4
send value 41 to fd 4
send value 43 to fd 4
send value 45 to fd 4
send value 47 to fd 4
send value 49 to fd 4
   -->> receiveAndSend(): in_fd = 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.027 - pid=22078: prime 3 from file descriptor 3
   Child at work
   read value 5 from fd 3
   send value 5 to fd 5
   read value 7 from fd 3
   send value 7 to fd 5
   read value 9 from fd 3
   read value 11 from fd 3
   send value 11 to fd 5
   read value 13 from fd 3
   send value 13 to fd 5
   read value 15 from fd 3
   read value 17 from fd 3
   send value 17 to fd 5
   read value 19 from fd 3
   send value 19 to fd 5
   read value 21 from fd 3
   read value 23 from fd 3
   send value 23 to fd 5
   read value 25 from fd 3
   send value 25 to fd 5
   read value 27 from fd 3
   read value 29 from fd 3
   send value 29 to fd 5
   read value 31 from fd 3
   send value 31 to fd 5
   read value 33 from fd 3
   read value 35 from fd 3
   send value 35 to fd 5
   read value 37 from fd 3
   send value 37 to fd 5
   read value 39 from fd 3
   read value 41 from fd 3
   send value 41 to fd 5
   read value 43 from fd 3
   send value 43 to fd 5
   read value 45 from fd 3
   read value 47 from fd 3
   send value 47 to fd 5
   read value 49 from fd 3
   send value 49 to fd 5
   ---- receiveAndSend(): recursing
      -->> receiveAndSend(): in_fd = 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.027 - pid=22079: prime 5 from file descriptor 4
      Child at work
      read value 7 from fd 4
      send value 7 to fd 5
      read value 11 from fd 4
      send value 11 to fd 5
      read value 13 from fd 4
      send value 13 to fd 5
      read value 17 from fd 4
      send value 17 to fd 5
      read value 19 from fd 4
      send value 19 to fd 5
      read value 23 from fd 4
      send value 23 to fd 5
      read value 25 from fd 4
      read value 29 from fd 4
      send value 29 to fd 5
      read value 31 from fd 4
      send value 31 to fd 5
      read value 35 from fd 4
      read value 37 from fd 4
      send value 37 to fd 5
      read value 41 from fd 4
      send value 41 to fd 5
      read value 43 from fd 4
      send value 43 to fd 5
      read value 47 from fd 4
      send value 47 to fd 5
      read value 49 from fd 4
      send value 49 to fd 5
      ---- receiveAndSend(): recursing
         -->> receiveAndSend(): in_fd = 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.028 - pid=22080: prime 7 from file descriptor 3
         Child at work
         read value 11 from fd 3
         send value 11 to fd 5
         read value 13 from fd 3
         send value 13 to fd 5
         read value 17 from fd 3
         send value 17 to fd 5
         read value 19 from fd 3
         send value 19 to fd 5
         read value 23 from fd 3
         send value 23 to fd 5
         read value 29 from fd 3
         send value 29 to fd 5
         read value 31 from fd 3
         send value 31 to fd 5
         read value 37 from fd 3
         send value 37 to fd 5
         read value 41 from fd 3
         send value 41 to fd 5
         read value 43 from fd 3
         send value 43 to fd 5
         read value 47 from fd 3
         send value 47 to fd 5
         read value 49 from fd 3
         ---- receiveAndSend(): recursing
            -->> receiveAndSend(): in_fd = 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.029 - pid=22081: prime 11 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.030 - pid=22081: prime 13 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.030 - pid=22081: prime 17 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.030 - pid=22081: prime 19 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.031 - pid=22081: prime 23 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.031 - pid=22081: prime 29 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.031 - pid=22081: prime 31 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.032 - pid=22081: prime 37 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.032 - pid=22081: prime 41 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.032 - pid=22081: prime 43 from file descriptor 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.033 - pid=22081: prime 47 from file descriptor 4
            <<-- receiveAndSend(): Child exits with status 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.033 - pid=22080: Child 22081 exited with status 0x0400
         <<-- receiveAndSend()
      ---- receiveAndSend(): returning
      <<-- receiveAndSend(): Child exits with status 4
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.034 - pid=22079: Child 22080 exited with status 0x0400
      <<-- receiveAndSend()
   ---- receiveAndSend(): returning
   <<-- receiveAndSend(): Child exits with status 3
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.034 - pid=22078: Child 22079 exited with status 0x0300
   <<-- receiveAndSend()
prime31: 2023-03-11 00:24:35.034 - pid=22078: Parent exits
$
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your implementation:

- when reading `p`, you only test for failure, not for end of file, hence you may continue with an invalid value of `p`.  You should just use:

  ```
  if (read(wr[pipeNr][0], &p, 4) < 4)
      return;
  ```
- testing for failure of the `close()` system call is useless, it does not matter for the purpose of the algorithm and obfuscates the code.
- conversely, you should test for failure of the `fork()` and `pipe()` system calls, indicating that you are running out of system resources.
- you should check that `pipeNr` is less than `35` to avoid a buffer overflow, which will occur if the main process writes too many numbers to the initial pipe (> 149). Passing the array length would make the function more generic.
- the purpose of the `wait(0)` (or more readably `wait(NULL)`) system call is to avoid exiting the intial process until all prime numbers have been printed.  Removing this call lets the program output all primes but some or all of them may be printed after the initial process has already exited to the shell.
- the `receiveAndSend` function only does something in the child process. The current process just waits for the child process to exit. This is incorrect.  The only reason why the program seems to work with the `wait()` calls removed is the child process writes to the pipe buffer, then recurses and lets its child process read from the pipe.  This approach is limited by the pipe buffer size: with a longer stream, the pipe buffer would fill up and `write` would wait for the pipe reader to read from the pipe, which will not happen because the next process has not been created yet.

  To fix this problem, you should just recurse in the child process and perform the filtering in the parent process.
- after this fix, the `wait()` call will still hang because the child process is waiting for the next number from the pipe.  The parent process must close the `wr[pipeNr][1]` handle for the child process to get an end of file on its `wr[pipeNr - 1][0]` handle and exit.

Here is a modified version with a `main` function that takes a maximum value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void receiveAndSend(int wr[][2], int pipeNr, int pipeSize) {
    int p;

    close(wr[pipeNr][1]);
    if (read(wr[pipeNr][0], &p, 4) < 4)
        return;

    printf("prime %d, from file descriptor %d\n", p, wr[pipeNr][0]);

    pipeNr++;
    if (pipeNr >= pipeSize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "too many primes\n");
        return;
    }
    if (pipe(wr[pipeNr])) {
        perror("pipe");
        return;
    }

    // enclose all of this in new fork
    int sec = fork();
    if (sec < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return;
    }
    if (sec == 0) {
        receiveAndSend(wr, pipeNr, pipeSize);
    } else {
        close(wr[pipeNr][0]);
        int j;
        while (read(wr[pipeNr - 1][0], &j, 4) > 0) {
            if (j % p != 0) {
                if (write(wr[pipeNr][1], &j, 4) < 0) {
                    perror("Write x");
                }
            }
        }
        close(wr[pipeNr - 1][0]);
        close(wr[pipeNr][1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int wr[35][2];
    int maxp = 100;

    if (argc >= 2)
        maxp = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (pipe(wr[0])) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    int sec = fork();
    if (sec < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }
    if (sec == 0) {
        receiveAndSend(wr, 0, sizeof(wr) / sizeof(wr[0]));
    } else {
        close(wr[0][0]);
        for (int p = 2; p < maxp; p++) {
            write(wr[0][1], &p, 4);
        }
        close(wr[0][1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sessions:

```
chqrlie ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./230311-prime 50
prime 2, from file descriptor 3
prime 3, from file descriptor 4
prime 5, from file descriptor 5
prime 7, from file descriptor 6
prime 11, from file descriptor 7
prime 13, from file descriptor 8
prime 17, from file descriptor 9
prime 19, from file descriptor 10
prime 23, from file descriptor 11
prime 29, from file descriptor 12
prime 31, from file descriptor 13
prime 37, from file descriptor 14
prime 41, from file descriptor 15
prime 43, from file descriptor 16
prime 47, from file descriptor 17
```

```
chqrlie ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./230311-prime 200
prime 2, from file descriptor 3
prime 3, from file descriptor 4
prime 5, from file descriptor 5
prime 7, from file descriptor 6
prime 11, from file descriptor 7
[...]
prime 127, from file descriptor 33
prime 131, from file descriptor 34
prime 137, from file descriptor 35
prime 139, from file descriptor 36
prime 149, from file descriptor 37
too many primes
```

Note these further remarks:

- the `read` and `write` system calls are not guaranteed to return `4` on success, they would return a smaller value for multiple reasons, eg: if the pipe buffer is almost full for `write` or almost empty for `read`.  In practice, this does not happen because the pipe buffer length is a multiple of `4` and the pipe buffer never fills up because of the small number of iterations.
- there is no need for an array of handle pairs: the function `receiveAndSend` could just get the read handle as an argument and use a local array of 2 handles for the `pipe` call.

Here is a modified version without an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void receiveAndSend(int fd) {
    int p;

    if (read(fd, &p, 4) < 4)
        return;

    printf("prime %d, from file descriptor %d\n", p, fd);

    int wr[2];
    if (pipe(wr)) {
        perror("pipe");
        return;
    }

    // enclose all of this in new fork
    int sec = fork();
    if (sec < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return;
    }
    if (sec == 0) {
        close(wr[1]);
        receiveAndSend(wr[0]);
    } else {
        close(wr[0]);
        int j;
        while (read(fd, &j, 4) > 0) {
            if (j % p != 0) {
                if (write(wr[1], &j, 4) < 0) {
                    perror("Write x");
                }
            }
        }
        close(fd);
        close(wr[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int maxp = 100;

    if (argc >= 2)
        maxp = atoi(argv[1]);

    int wr[2];
    if (pipe(wr)) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    int sec = fork();
    if (sec < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }
    if (sec == 0) {
        close(wr[1]);
        receiveAndSend(wr[0]);
    } else {
        close(wr[0]);
        for (int p = 2; p < maxp; p++) {
            write(wr[1], &p, 4);
        }
        close(wr[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This version accepts larger limits but will run out of resources for relatively small numbers of primes:

```
chqrlie ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./230311-prime 2000
prime 2, from file descriptor 3
prime 3, from file descriptor 4
prime 5, from file descriptor 5
prime 7, from file descriptor 6
prime 11, from file descriptor 7
[...]
prime 1571, from file descriptor 250
prime 1579, from file descriptor 251
prime 1583, from file descriptor 252
prime 1597, from file descriptor 253
prime 1601, from file descriptor 254
pipe: Too many open files
```

Closing `fd` in the child process removes the limitation on file handles:

```
    if (sec == 0) {
        close(fd);
        close(wr[1]);
        receiveAndSend(wr[0]);
    } ...
```

But since all processes run concurrently, the limit will hit when `fork` fails:

```
chqrlie ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./230311-prime 100000
prime 2, from file descriptor 3
prime 3, from file descriptor 4
prime 5, from file descriptor 3
prime 7, from file descriptor 4
prime 11, from file descriptor 3
[...]
prime 33601, from file descriptor 3
prime 33613, from file descriptor 4
prime 33617, from file descriptor 3
prime 33619, from file descriptor 4
prime 33623, from file descriptor 3
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```